# display an image onchange of picklist value

Tags: visualforce

i need to replace instead `'Time selected is no longer available'` i want to display a cross image and instead `AVAILABLE` i want to display a check image. How can i achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

### VFP

```
<apex:pageBlock id="teacherPageBlock">    
                        <div style="margin-top: 10px; padding: 45px;"> 
                            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!WrapTS}" var="item" id="teacherBlock">

                                <apex:column headerValue="Teacher" value="{!item.t1.First_Name__c} {!item.t1.Name}"/>
                                <!--   <apex:param id="teacherid" name="teacherId" value="{!item.t1.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedTId}"/> -->
                                <apex:column headerValue="Subject" value="{!item.t1.Subject__c}"/>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Room" value="{!item.t1.Room_Assignment__c}"/>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Time">
                                    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedTime}">
                                     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  action="{!checkTeacherSched}" reRender="teacherBlock"/>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue=""></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="9:00AM - 10:00AM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="10:00AM - 11:00AM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="11:00AM - 12:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="12:00PM - 1:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="1:00PM - 2:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="2:00PM - 3:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="3:00PM - 4:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="4:00PM - 5:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  action="{!checkTeacherSched}" reRender="teacherBlock"/>
                                    </apex:selectList>
                                </apex:column>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Status">
                                    <apex:outputText value="{!strCheck}">

                                    </apex:outputText>

                                </apex:column>

                            </apex:pageBlockTable>
                        </div>
                    </apex:pageBlock>
```

### Controller snippet

```
//CHECK TEACHER SCHEDULE//

public void checkTeacherSched(){
    strCheck = null;
    wrapTeaSched = new list<schedule__c>();

    for(schedule__c myTime : [Select id, name, teacher__c, time__c, student__c, parent__c, teacher_cname__c 
        from schedule__c WHERE teacher__c =: myTea AND time__c =: selectedTime ]){
            checkSchedTeaID.add(myTime.id);


       //system.assertequals(checkSchedTeaId + '','test');
       if(checkSchedTeaId!= null){
           strCheck = 'Time selected is no longer available';  
       }
       else if(checkSchedTeaId== null){
           strCheck = 'AVAILABLE';
       }
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

Upload your images for cross and check as a static resource.

In your VF page instead of displaying the `strCheck` string, display your images and use conditional rendering.

**Something like:**

```
<apex:column headerValue="Status">
    <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.TestZip,
                      'images/Cross.jpg')}" rendered="{!IF(strCheck ='Time selected is no longer available',true,false)}"/>

    <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.TestZip,
                      'images/Check.jpg')}" rendered="{!IF(strCheck ='AVAILABLE',true,false)}"/>

</apex:column>
```

Comment: can i do the conditional statement in the controller? and tje image will just display the result?

Comment: Yes you can do it. In this case you will have one `Apex:image` tag and the value of the url will be set in a variable in your controller based on your logic.

Comment: how can i set url value from controller? string?

Comment: Yes. But why dont you do it like the way I have suggested?

Comment: You are welcome..glad it worked :)